# Lines look different on different zoom rate

Tags: javascript, line, draw, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I am using ArcGIS JavaScript 3.27 APIs.

Below, I have attached how the lines look on different zoom rate.

These lines are drawn based on this code. (JavaScript Code)

```
var baseX = Number, baseY = Number
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i ++) {
    var posArray = [
        [ baseX + i, baseY + i ],
        [ baseX + (i + 1), baseY + (i + 1) ]
    ];

    var graphic = new Polyline(map.spatialReference);
    graphic.addPath(posArray);

    var symbol = new SimpleFillSymbol(
        SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
        new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new Color([ 255, 255, 255 ]), 1),
        new Color([ 58, 58, 58, 0.8 ])
    );
    var graphic = new Graphic(geometry, symbol);
    map.graphics.add(graphic);
}
```

And in normal, the lines drawn should be straight but as you see below, the lines drawn are not straight.

It looks straight on only max-zoom rate and on other zoom rates, it doesn't look straight.

Any solutions?

[image: Minimum Zoom Rate]

[image]

[image]
[image: Maximum Zoom Rate]

Comment: if you are using google maps, why don't you use `Polyline` from google maps for this?

Comment: Without knowing what your spatial reference is, or what `baseX` and `baseY` are, I'd guess you're running into a rounding error.